# Combine rows based on multiple columns and keep all unique values

Tags: r

I have a dataset with User Information. For a specific user I have often multiple rows with more or less complete information.  I want to summarize all rows that belong to a customer on the basis of First_Name, Last_Name, Street while keeping all information of the other columns and if there are two unique observation for a specific column I want to collapse them with ",".

This is what the df looks like

```
First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n

Mike       Smith      X     abc     ab     a
Mike       Smith      X     abc     ad     b
John       Smith      Y     xyz     xy     n
John       Smith      Y     xyz     xm     NA
```

My desired output would be

```
 First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n

 Mike       Smith      X     abc     ab,ad     a,b
 John       Smith      Y     xyz     xy,xm       n
```

I would like using dplyr and tried something with

```
df %>% 
group_by(First_Name,Last_Name, Street) %>%
summarise_all(funs())
```

The problem with that function is that I only had the option of using something like the mean or the first occuring value for a column and this would mean the loss of values. What I would like are columns with all unique values without NA's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own summarization function like

`concat_unique <- function(x){paste(unique(x),  collapse=',')}`

and then apply it using
`summarize_all(concat_unique)`

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(First_Name, Last_Name, Street) %>%
  # Replace NA with ""
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), ""))) %>%
  # Combine all strings
  summarize_all(funs(toString(unique(.)))) %>%
  # Replace the strings ended with ", "
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., ", $", ""))) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#   First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
#   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
# 1 John       Smith     Y      xyz     xy, xm n      
# 2 Mike       Smith     X      abc     ab, ad a, b
```

After seeing others answer, I realized that we don't have to deal with `NA` and `,` as strings. The following is more efficient.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(First_Name, Last_Name, Street) %>%
  # Combine all strings
  summarize_all(funs(toString(unique(.[!is.na(.)])))) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#   First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
#   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
# 1 John       Smith     Y      xyz     xy, xm n      
# 2 Mike       Smith     X      abc     ab, ad a, b
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
Mike       Smith      X     abc     ab     a
Mike       Smith      X     abc     ad     b
John       Smith      Y     xyz     xy     n
John       Smith      Y     xyz     xm     NA',
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I was literally going to post the exact same solution, but I did not forget the `unique()` :D

Comment: Thank you very much that works well. I also tried all the other proposed solutions and it's always the same result. Some of the rows where you have the exact First_Name,Last_Name, Street combination get aggregated and the strings are combined. But some rows with the exact same combination of the three colums are still not aggregated what could be the reason for that ?

Comment: @Nico.444 It could be that there are slight differences in `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, and `Street combination`. Otherwise, I cannot think of other reasons.

Comment: It's really weird I have for example two rows with exact combination of Names and Street but when I filter for those strings I only get one of the rows as a result. It's like some strings are not recognized even though they are the same combination of letters.

Comment: @Nico.444 Perhaps there is a space at the end of a string, causing the strings looks similar bu different.

Comment: @www Yep that's exactly what it was there were some whitespaces at the end of the strings. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep them as a vector, instead of converting them to a single character string, you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(First_Name,Last_Name, Street) %>%
  summarise_all(~list(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))) %>% 
  print.data.frame

#   First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
# 1       John     Smith      Y     xyz xy, xm       n
# 2       Mike     Smith      X     abc ab, ad    a, b
```

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) .(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
   , by = .(First_Name,Last_Name, Street)]

#    First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
# 1:       Mike     Smith      X     abc  ab,ad     a,b
# 2:       John     Smith      Y     xyz  xy,xm       n
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(First_Name, Last_Name, Street) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(paste0(unique(.[!is.na(.)]), collapse= ",")))

  First_Name Last_Name Street Column1 Colum2 Colum_n
  <fct>      <fct>     <fct>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
1 John       Smith     Y      xyz     xy,xm  n      
2 Mike       Smith     X      abc     ab,ad  a,b
```

First, it is grouping by "First_Name", "Last_Name" and "Street". Then, it takes all the unique non-NA values and collapses them into one string.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan oh, that was redundant. Also, my code is almost the same as yours, so I can remove it if you feel it's too close to yours.

Comment: No, it's fine. Mine makes a vector, but this make a single character value.